# how to set data rate in case of tcp using ns2?

Tags: tcp, ns2

I was trying to send ftp packets using tcp. which parameter in ns2 should i use to change the data rate of sender? i tried using the following to vary between 2 Mbps and 8 Mbps but seems like both are giving same results and does not vary the sender data rate.

```
$ftp($i) set rate_ 2Mb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "set rate_" option for TCP-based applications like FTP in ns2. TCP has its own flow control (e.g. sliding window) and congestion control mechanism to control the data rate. 
Whereas the UDP-based traffic applications, e.g Application/Traffic/CBR, has this option.

You can refer to this ns document:
http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/doc/node516.html

You may want to experiment with different TCP window sizes, link bandwidth, and the packet numbers produced by FTP and see what data rate you can achieve.